# Mutating Method sent to immutable object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've coded an app that allows its users to "favorite" items in a tableview. E.g. tapping on a button adds the items in a selected cell to a favorites table view. The below code was working perfectly until I updated my version of Xcode. Now, when tapping on the star button, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Does anyone know why this might be? All of my necessary properties are mutable.

Thanks.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableData *data;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Strains;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *strainsfinal;
-(void)updateStrains;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize data;
@synthesize Strains;
@synthesize strainsfinal;
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    [self updateStrains];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Add in your API key here:
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"KEY HERE"];


    strainsfinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSObject *testObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"strains"];
    if (testObject != nil) {
        [strainsfinal addObjectsFromArray:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"strains"] mutableCopy]];

                return YES;
    }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSMutableArray *oldStrains = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:strainsfinal];

    NSLog(@"count is %i", oldStrains.count);
    NSMutableArray *blankArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      Strains = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


    if (oldStrains.count < Strains.count) {
        for (int x = oldStrains.count; x < Strains.count; x++) {
            [oldStrains addObject:[Strains objectAtIndex:x]];
        }


    }
    if (oldStrains.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"count is %i",oldStrains.count);

        blankArray = [oldStrains copy];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = nil;

        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Title"
                                                     ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        Strains = [blankArray  sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        int count = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *item in Strains) {
            [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"position"];
            if ([item valueForKey:@"checked"] ==  nil) {
                bool checked = NO;
                [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checked]  forKey:@"checked"];
            }
            count++;
        }

        [strainsfinal removeAllObjects];
        [strainsfinal addObjectsFromArray:[Strains mutableCopy]];
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure that you're connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;    
}

-(void)updateStrains {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strainsfinal forKey:@"strains"];
    NSLog(@"updated strains %@",strainsfinal);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // this will save you UserDefaults

}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegate;
    NSIndexPath *currentDetailPath;
    UINavigationController *navController;
    bool loaded;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Strains;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *favoritesArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *strainsFiltered;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *StrainTableView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize searchResults;
    @synthesize StrainTableView;
    @synthesize favoritesArray;
    @synthesize Strains;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(arrayUpdated)
                                                     name:@"arrayupdated"
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    -(void)arrayUpdated
    {
       Strains = appdelegate.strainsfinal;
        [StrainTableView reloadData];

    }

    - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            return [searchResults count];
        } else {
            return [Strains count];
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *customerTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

        StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[StrainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customerTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)

            cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:customerTableIdentifier];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;


        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            NSLog(@"Using the search results");

            cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];

            cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];


        } else {

            cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];

         //   cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customeremail"];

            cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];

        }

        NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

        //  [item setObject:cell forKey:@"CustomerCell"];
        BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];


        UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        button.frame = frame;
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.accessoryView = button;

        return cell;

    }

    -(void)notificationCheckButtonTapped{

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = currentDetailPath;

        if (indexPath != Nil)
        {

            NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            BOOL isItChecked =  [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
     NSMutableArray *quickArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:Strains];
            [quickArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:item];

            [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"];
       Strains = [quickArray copy];

      [StrainTableView reloadData];

        }

    }

    - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
    {
        NSLog(@"made it here and event is %@",event);

        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.StrainTableView];
        NSIndexPath *  indexPath ;
        indexPath =  [self.StrainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
        NSLog(@"indexpath is below");
        NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
        if (indexPath != Nil)
        {

            NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            BOOL isItChecked =  [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
      NSMutableArray *quickArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:Strains];
            [quickArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:item];


            [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"];
            Strains = [quickArray copy];

            [StrainTableView reloadData];

        }

    }
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        // if (loaded == NO) {

        appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        Strains = [appdelegate.strainsfinal copy];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(notificationCheckButtonTapped)
                                                     name:@"detailChecked"
                                                   object:nil];

        if (Strains == Nil) {
            Strains = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:appdelegate.strainsfinal];
        }

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"] != Nil) {

            NSData *dataSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"];
            favoritesArray =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
        }
  }
        loaded = YES;
        [StrainTableView reloadData];

    }
```

Comment: "Does anyone know why this might be" Yes, I think we all do. It's because you can't `setObject:ForKey:` to an NSDictionary — only to an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: As an aside: You do not need `@synthesize` is you access all the ivars via `self.` The ivars will be automatically synthesized with a leading underscore. It is also common convention that variable and method names begin with a lower case letter and class with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

These lines, or similar, are the source of the trouble:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in Strains) {
    [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"position"];
    // ...
}
```

Assuming that you are right that `Strains` consists of NSDictionary objects, you cannot say `setValue:forKey:` to an NSDictionary. It is immutable. You would need to derive an NSMutableDictionary from your NSDictionary and say `setValue:forKey:` (or, better, `setObject:forKey:`) to that.

Comment: And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsdictionary_and_nsmutabledictionary

Comment: Ahhh. Okay everywhere else I've used NSMutableDictionary. So just changing that line to (NSMutableDictionary *item in Strains) ... won't work? Sorry for the newb question :P

Comment: In general what matters is what something _is_, not what you _say_ it is. If it is in fact an NSDictionary, you can't say `setValue:forKey:` to it, no matter how to typologize it. - By the way, I do not for one moment believe your original claim that this code worked fine until you updated Xcode. Objective-C did not magically change overnight.

Comment: Believe it; because it's true ;) P.S. - I'm sorry my claim insults you so heavily. Can't we all just get along?

Comment: Okay, maybe Objective-C did change overnight! I've been wrong before, I can handle it. (Sob....)

Answer (score 2):

In the statement

```
blankArray = [oldStrains copy];
```

blankArray's contents become immutable.

Then later inthe code:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in Strains) {
    [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"position"];
```

`item` will be an immutable `NSDictionary`.

Try:
    blankArray = [oldStrains mutableCopy];

The section in `checkButtonTapped:` probably can be simplified to:

```
NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL isItChecked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
[item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"];
[Strains replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:item];
```

Comment: Sharp eye, there, @zaph.

Comment: @matt Lol, I had such high hopes for this answer. I changed the line to blankArray = [oldStrains mutableCopy]; still no dice. Crashed with the same error.

Comment: With the debugger follow `Strains` to find out where it's contents become immutable. Or sprinkle in some class name logging: `NSLog(@"class name: %@", NSStringFromClass([Strains class]));` and/or `NSLog(@"class name: %@", NSStringFromClass([Strains[0] class]));`.

Comment: The crash happens at the end of my checkButtonTapped method in viewcontroller.m at this line:  [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"];

Comment: In that method is: `Strains = [quickArray copy];` which again is probably not what you want. Why not just assign it: `Strains = quickArray`.

Comment: See updated eidit. Avoid copying collections if possible.

Comment: Implemented your edit; still getting the crash. When I comment this line out: [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"]; the crash disappears (though naturally, then the method doesn't work). What is it about that line that is seemingly immutable? Lol!

Comment: Still: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: You are going to have to locate all the places the `NSMutableDictionary` is being changed to `NSDictionary`. The best course is to eliminate the copies. As in an above comment use logging to provide the class mutability, ot lldb `po` command.

Answer (score 0):

At some place, you declared it to be NSDictionary while you intented it to be NSMutableDictionary